# How to statistically test data points that are coming from two groups of distributions?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, inference

Suppose we have two groups of data points, i,e, **A** and **B**, and we want to know if they are coming from two different distributions or just one? The candidate solutions are standard t-test or Kolmogorov Smirnov tests.

But suppose instead of two groups of data points **A** and **B**, we have two sets of groups of data points, set **A** = {$A_1$, $A_2$, ..., $A_n$} and **B** = {$B_1$, $B_2$, ..., $B_n$} and we want to statistically test if they are coming from two groups of distributions or not. One simple candidate solution could be considering all the data points in set **A** as one group of data points and all the data points in set **B** as another group of data points and then perform t-test and Kolmogorov Smirnov tests on them. But I am looking for some sort of more informative and systematic test.
**Is there any other solution to compare these two sets of data points?**

Comment: While it's not a test, you could just look at a plot of the densities (or cumulative densities) of A and B. There's probably more value in that than just running a hypothesis test. The Komologrov-Smirnov test is probably the most widely used for assessing whether two data sets come from the same distribution. Another common way of checking similarity is through the Kullback Leibler divergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question raises a number of important issues about detecting when two datasets come from different distributions. I will discuss several
situations and several possible tests, but this answer is only an
introduction to a large and complicated topic.

(1) In addition to the tests mentioned in your Question, you could also test to see if the two samples come from
distributions with different variances. In the sample below,
the variances are $\sigma_1^2 = 5^2= 25$ and
$\sigma_2^2 =10^2 = 100.$ This seems to be a huge difference,
but differences in variances are not always easy to detect.
In this case we detect a significant difference at the 10% level,
but not at the f% level. (Using R below.)

```
set.seed(1234)
x1 = rnorm(50, 100, 5)
x2 = rnorm(50, 100, 10)
boxplot(x1, x2, col="skyblue2", horizontal=T)
```

[image]

```
var.test(x1, x2)

        F test to compare two variances

data:  x1 and x2
F = 0.41011, num df = 19, denom df = 19, p-value = 0.05912
alternative hypothesis: 
  true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1623246 1.0361108
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
         0.4101052
```

However, with larger samples $(n_1=n_2=70)$ from the same distributions, we do find a significant difference, with a P-value very near $0.$

```
set.seed(1233)
v1 = rnorm(70, 100, 5)
v2 = rnorm(70, 100, 10)
var.test(v1, v2)$p.val
[1] 1.022782e-08
```

(2) It is possible for distributions of different shapes to
have equal mean and equal variances. Then tests for different means and variances are neither appropriate mor useful.

```
set.seed(1235)
y1 = rnorm(100, 8, 4)  # pop var 16
y2 = rchisq(100, 8)    # pop var 16
boxplot(y1, y2, col="skyblue2", horizontal=T)
```

[image]

Although, it doesn't have very good power, the Kolmogorov-Smirnov
test does detect that `y1` and `y1` are from different distributions;
the P-value is $0.025 < 0.05 = 5\%,$ rejecting the null hypothesis
the the populations are the same at the 5% level.

```
ks.test(y1, y2)

        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  y1 and y2
D = 0.21, p-value = 0.02431
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

The K-S test compares two empirical CDFs (ECDFs) which are plots that
seek to use the samples to approximate the population CDFs. In the plot below
the ECDF plotted in blue is the one from the normal sample. The K-S test
statistic $D=0.21$ is the maximum vertical difference between the two ECDFs (occurring for data values somewhere around $7.5).$

```
hdr = "ECDFs of a normal sample (blue) and a chi-squared sample"
plot(ecdf(y2), col="brown", main=hdr)
lines(ecdf(y1), col="blue")
```

[image]

Sometimes you can guess informally that samples are from different
distributions if the ECDF plots seem to be of distinctly different
shapes--even if sample sizes are too small for the K-S test to detect
a significant difference. You might also compare histograms of the
two samples, but ECDFs sometimes work better.

(3) Sometimes it takes surprisingly large samples before differences between two distributions become obvious. Here is an example with
a sample from a normal distribution and a sample from a uniform distribution--with matching means and variances

```
set.seed(1236)
w1 = rnorm(70, .5, sqrt(1/12))  # mean 1/2, var 1/12
w2 = runif(70, 0, 1)            # mean 1/2, var 1/12

ks.test(w1,w2)

        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  w1 and w2
D = 0.12857, p-value = 0.6128
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

To my eye, neither histograms nor ECDF plots make it obvious that the two samples
come from different distributions. Below are the histograms (with population densities shown for reference).

[image]

This was not just an "unlucky" pair of datasets. With sample sizes of $n = 70,$ the K-S test can distinguish between samples from these two distributions less than 7% of the time, as illustrated by the simulation below with $100,000$ pairs of such samples.

```
set.seed(1237)
pv = replicate(10^5, ks.test(rnorm(70,.5,sqrt(1/12)),runif(70))$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.06889
```

(4) In order to show some additional methods for comparing datasets from potentially different distributions, we return to the second (larger) datasets `v1` and `v2`in part (1).

First, the K-S test finds a significant difference at the 2% level between the two populations.

```
ks.test(v1, v2)$p.val
[1] 0.01151174
```

Histograms of these two samples look different in shape. We show frequencies for each histogram interval.

```
cutp = seq(80,130, len=6)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 hist(v1, br=cutp, ylim=c(0,40), col="skyblue2", label=T)
 hist(v2, br=cutp, ylim=c(0,40), col="skyblue2", label=T)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

We can use these frequencies to make the required contingency table
`TAB` for a chi-squared test whether the two populations are the same.

```
TBL = rbind(c(2,30,11,1,0), c(9,18,13,7,3));  TBL
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2   30   11    1    0
[2,]    9   18   13    7    3
```

Our first attempt to use the R procedure `chisq.test` gives a warning message on account of the small counts for histogram bars in the right tails. These small counts call into question whether the chi-squared statistic is approximately distributed as $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = 5-1 = 4),$ and thus whether the P-value is accurate.

```
chisq.test(TBL)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 14.799, df = 4, p-value = 0.005138

Warning message:
In chisq.test(TBL) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Traditionally, this kind of difficulty would be handled by combining the two highest intervals into one interval $(110, 130)$ with sufficiently large counts. However, the implementation of `chisq.test` in R allows for
simulation of a more accurate P-value (using parameter `sim=T`) as below:

```
chisq.test(TBL, sim=T)$p.val
[1] 0.002998501
```

Another possible test is Fisher's Exact Test. Traditionally, this test
was used only for $2 \times 2$ tables and usually for small counts.
However, the implementation of `fisher.test` in R accepts larger tables.
[If you try to use too large a table you may exceed the memory allocated
to R.] Here is the result (significant at the 1% level) from Fisher's Exact Test with our $2\times 5$ table.

```
fisher.test(TBL)

         Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  TBL
p-value = 0.003792
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

Sometimes the chi-squared test or Fisher's Exact Test have better power
(higher probability of rejection when populations truly differ) than
the K-S test.